# ECS Service connect could not resolve host

Tags: amazon-web-services, network-programming, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I’m trying to use service connect to give a dns to a task (service1) that is on a private subnet and other task (service2) calls using this dns from a public subnet, but when I try do a curl, I receive the error: could not resolve host.
I saw that the address is not updating on the etc/hosts (service2)..

I tried updating the /etc/hosts file manually, and it worked, but this shouldn't be a manual process

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming across this problem now. I think it is due to a race condition in how multiple services are deployed. If service 2 is deployed before service 1, then the /etc/hosts file wouldn't have been written with the service connect dns. The same thing will happen any time you add a new service to service connect. The fix is to just redeploy the service. Next time it will have the correct dns written. If you are using cloudformation then you can also set dependencies between different services for when they are deployed.